# Interpretation of implication symbol in modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Suppose we have two propositions p and q, and an implication of this form:

p → □q

I can think of two potential interpretations of the meaning of this in terms of possible worlds:

1. If p is true in this world, q must be true in all possible worlds.
2. In any world where p is true, it necessarily follows q is true in that possible world as well. But this should not be taken to rule out that there may be worlds where neither is true. For example, it is necessarily true that if Steve is a bachelor than Steve does not have a living spouse, but there can still be worlds where Steve is not a bachelor and does have a living spouse.

Which of these, if either, is the generally accepted meaning? If anyone can point to a reference by a professional that spells this out that'd be ideal, but if not I'll accept an answer based on personal expertise if there seems to be agreement among those answering.

Comment: What do you mean by "generally accepted meaning"? Modal logic is based on axioms so any proposition has only one "meaning"?

Comment: @Atamari - Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the axioms of basic modal logic don't deal explicitly with sets of "possible worlds" (the axioms [here](https://mally.stanford.edu/tutorial/modal.html) don't, for example) but conceptual and philosophical discussions of modal logic often make use of this concept. In general I believe the symbols in any formal axiomatic system are understood not to have any inherent meaning, any interpretation of their meaning requires a "model" of the system in the sense of [model theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/).

Comment: Your 2) would be [] (p->q), so I am leaning toward 1)  But I am having trouble imagining an application that does not involve p -> [] p first.  If p is necessarily either true or false by nature of its content, then p -> [] p.  if in addition [] (p->q) then p -> [] q.

Comment: @jobemark - Thanks, your first point seems like a good one in favor of 1)--the only thing I would want to confirm is that □(p → q) and p → □q are wholly independent in the sense that neither one can be derived from the other.

Comment: In this sense, if you are asking for an interpretation of a formula, you should give the model first. The truth value of many formulae depends on the accessibility relation.

Comment: The two propositions aren't independent.

Comment: It may be necessarily true that our single moon causes tides, so in any world where the Earth has one moon, there will be tides (i.e. [](p->q)).  But keeping that fact necessary, the fact there is one moon in reality does not imply that all worlds would have tides ( so p !-> []q ) because the same theory with many smal,l equally spaced moons would predict no tides.  So you cannot deduce 1 from 2.  All that is important is that they are not equivalent.  You don't need them to be independent.

Comment: @jobermark -- If they're not independent, I take it you're saying p → □q does imply □(p → q) though? I can't see how to derive that from the axioms [here](https://mally.stanford.edu/tutorial/modal.html) though, and it doesn't seem clear in terms of my understanding of the meaning either--I think p → □q means something like "if p is true in the world w under discussion, q is true in all worlds accessible from w", but if p is *not* true in w, then I don't see how we can rule out ~□(p → q), i.e. "it is not true that in all the worlds accessible from w where p is true, q is also true."

Comment: @Atamari - If I had thought about the model issue carefully I would have added something like "in whatever model philosophers most commonly use to interpret propositions in modal logic as referring to possible worlds", but reading a few articles like [this](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#PosWorSem) I get the impression that the Kripke semantics of modal logic described in Mauro's answer would fit the bill. As for your second point that they're not independent, do you agree with jobermark that □(p → q) does not imply p → □q? If so see my question in my last comment to jobermark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Kripke Semantics of modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) :

> A **Kripke frame** is a pair **(W,R)**, where **W** is a (possibly empty) set, and **R** is a binary relation on **W**. Elements of **W** are called nodes or worlds, and **R** is known as the accessibility relation.
>
> A **Kripke model** is a triple **(W,R,⊩)**, where **(W,R)** is a Kripke frame, and **⊩** is a relation between nodes of **W** and modal formulas, such that:
>
> > **w ⊩ ¬A** if and only if **w ⊮ A**,
> >
> > **w ⊩ A → B** if and only if **w ⊮ A** or **w ⊩ B**,
> >
> > **w ⊩ □A** if and only if **u ⊩ A** for all **u** such that **wRu**.
>
> We read **w ⊩ A** as “**w** satisfies **A**”, “**A** is satisfied in **w**”, or “**w** forces **A**”.
>
> The relation **⊩** is called the *satisfaction* relation, evaluation, or forcing relation. The satisfaction relation is uniquely determined by its value on propositional variables.

According to these semantical specifications, the truth-value of **p → □q** must be computed as :

> **w ⊩ p → □q**, i.e. “**p → □q** is satisfied in **w**”

as follows :

> either **p** is not satisfied (i.e. is *false*) in **w**, or **q** is satisfied in every **u** such that **wRu** (i.e. in all worlds accessible from **w**).

In simpler words : if **p** is true in a world, **q** must be true in all worlds accessible from it.